# snakemake : export DAG for a specific rule file

Tags: snakemake

I know we can export DAG of a snakemake pipeline with the command

```
snakemake --dag | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

My pipeline is separated in different .rules file, that can be run independantly.

I would like to generate a graph of a single .rules file but I haven't find a way yet, does anyone would know how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how individual `.rules` are defined, but it's possible to pass a specific `Snakefile` using `-s`:

```sh
snakemake -s step1.rules --dag | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

This might not work if the `.rules` files are defined partially (e.g. do not contain a default rule `all`).